# find coordinates of vertices of an undirected, unweighted graph

Tags: graph, coordinates, fractals, vertices, complex-networks

Suppose I have an undirected, unweighted graph, with 'N'(say) vertices. I'm trying to find the co-ordinates of the vertices of the graph.

I don't seem to understand, how can we get the coordinates of the graph, without any function being provided. Is there any standard method we adapt to get the co-ordinates of the graph?

I need these co-ordinates because I want to use them as input parameters(by collecting them and placing in a file and supplying this file as argument) to fd3 program, to calculate the fractal dimension of a network(given coordinates of graph).

Comment: What format is your graph in?

Comment: I have adjacency matrix of the graph

Comment: My understanding of adjacency matrices is that they do not actually say anything about the vertices--only the connections between them.  Thus, you might as well label them 1 through N, and pick arbitrary locations for them.  You can use a graph-plotting program to give you coordinates if you want ones that look good.

Comment: so, you say, that there is no way, that I can get the vertices ?

is there any algorithm to find out fractal dimension of a complex network, provided the adjacency matrix of a graph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Cluster Growing Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension_on_networks#The_Cluster_Growing_Method) to get the fractal dimension of the system, as opposed to trying to use a box-counting algorithm.  It is much better suited to the task when the vertices are not associated with physical space.

Comment: excuse me sir! can I get the implementation of the algorithm anywhere for reference ?